# How to assign serial count in json array using Ruby?

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to assign serial counting to JSON array using ruby. Here is my example JSON

```
{
    "product_name" : "Prod 1",
    "product_description" : "Prod Description 1",
    "product_id" : "111",
    "product_attribute" : [{
            "name" : "Size",
            "value" : "10 mm"
        }, {
            "name" : "Color",
            "value" : "Red"
        }, {
            "name" : "Width",
            "value" : "25 mm"
        }, {
            "name" : "Length",
            "value" : "60 mm"
        }
    ]
}
```

My expected result is as how to assign a new key will count the array of product attribute and assign value dynamically

```
{
    "product_name" : "Prod 1",
    "product_description" : "Prod Description 1",
    "product_id" : "111",
    "product_attribute" : [{
            "name" : "Size",
            "value" : "10 mm",
            "key_num" : 1
        }, {
            "name" : "Color",
            "value" : "Red",
            "key_num" : 2
        }, {
            "name" : "Width",
            "value" : "25 mm",
            "key_num" : 3
        }, {
            "name" : "Length",
            "value" : "60 mm",
            "key_num" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above you can see i added "key_num" 1 to 4. I can have product attribute sometimes as 5,10,8 etc. and i need to assign those "key_num" dynamically based on count of product_attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, the easiest way would be to convert json to ruby map, apply the modifications and convert it back.

```rb
require 'json'
map = JSON.parse json

map["product_attribute"].each.with_index(1) do |h, idx|
  h["key_num"] = idx # mutating the map inplace
end

JSON.dump map
#⇒ "{...[{\"name\":\"Size\",\"value\":\"10 mm\",\"key_num\":1},...}"
```